# Split Files - Redshift Copy Command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

[image]
Hi,

I would like to know if the following the option A in the above image is a valid answer to the question and why is option C incorrect.

As per the [documentation on splitting data into multiple files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_splitting-data-files.html):

> Split your data into files so that the number of files is a multiple of the number of slices in your cluster. That way Amazon Redshift can divide the data evenly among the slices. The number of slices per node depends on the node size of the cluster. For example, each DS2.XL compute node has two slices, and each DS2.8XL compute node has 32 slices. For more information about the number of slices that each node size has, go to About Clusters and Nodes in the Amazon Redshift Cluster Management Guide.

Shouldn't option C, split the data into 10 files of equal size be the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A" is correct because of the nature of S3.  S3 takes time to "look up" the object you are accessing and then transfers the data to the requestor.  This "look up" time is on the order of .5 sec. and a lot of data can be transferred in that amount of time.  The worst case of this (and I have seen this) is breaking the data into one S3 object per row of data.  This means that most of the COPY time will be in "look up" time, not transfer time.  My own analysis of this (years ago) showed that objects of 100MB will spend less than 50% of the COPY time in object look ups. So 1GB is likely a good safe and future proofed size target.

"C" is wrong because you want to have as many independent parallel S3 data transfer occurring during the COPY (within reason and network card bandwith).  Since Redshift will start one S3 object per slice and there are multiple slices per node in Redshift.  The minimal number of slices is 2 for the small node types so you would want at least 20 S3 objects and many more for the larger node types.

Combining these you want many S3 objects but not a lot of small (<1GB) objects.  Big enough that object look up time is not a huge overhead and lots of objects so all the slices will be busy doing COPY work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the correct answer because

- Unless you know the exact size of the output files (combined) you won't be able to split to exactly 10 and if you do this redshift will probably write file by file so the unload will be slow
- It is not the optimal because the more smaller files you have, the better it becomes because you will utilize all the cores/nodes you have in the redshift cluster on unload and on copy later if you needed to load this data again

Comment: Thank you, makes sense!